# Passing 3 textbox values to a javascript function from ASPX

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I want to pass three textbox values to a javascript function. However its not working.Any help is really appreciated.This is what I have tried.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ibut_cheque2" runat="server" target="_blank"
OnClientClick='<%# string.Format("window.open(\"Product.aspx?pid=\" +
document.getElementById(\"{0}\").value & chdate=\" + 
document.getElementById(\"{1}\").value & pname=\" + 
document.getElementById(\"{2}\").value, 
null,\"scrollbars=yes,top=10,left=10\", \"true\");", 
Form.FindControl("txt_voucher").ClientID,
Form.FindControl("txtbox_chqdate").ClientID,
Form.FindControl("txtbox_chprovider").ClientID)%>'
AlternateText="Print" CssClass="btn5" ForeColor="White" ToolTip="Print Cheque" />
```

Comment: Can you tell what you actually want to do in detail

Comment: Actually I need to pass these 3 textbox values to another page.And capture these values into a variable in the other page.

Comment: instead of using javascript function you can use Session to store value from one page and retrive those value in another page like this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47277535/how-to-retrieve-the-value-from-one-page-to-another-in-asp-net/47278619#47278619

Comment: There are a few ways to do this better ... Could be via `SessionState` or `PreviousPage` property ... And in my opinion you'd better do this in .cs and not in .aspx

Answer (score 1):

On first Page Button click code

```
<script>
var value1="value1";
var value2="value2";
var queryString = "?para1=" + value1 + "&para2=" + value2;
window.location.href = "page2.html" + queryString;
</script>
```

On Second Page

```
<script>

var queryString = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search);
queryString = queryString.substring(1);
var queries = queryString.split("&");
for (var i = 0; i < queries.length; i++)
{
  document.write(queries[i] + "<br>");
}

</script>
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

```
     <asp:Button ID="PrintCheck" runat="server" target="_blank" 
     OnClientClick='openWindow()'   Text="Print Cheque" CssClass="btn5" 
     ForeColor="White" Width="120px" ToolTip="Print Cheque" />

     <script type="text/javascript">
     function openWindow() {
     var payname = document.getElementById('<%=txtbox_chprovider.ClientID 
      %>').value;
      var chdate = document.getElementById('<%=txtbox_chqdate.ClientID 
      %>').value;
      var chamount = document.getElementById('<%=txt_chamount.ClientID 
      %>').value;
    window.open("Product.aspx?payname=" + payname + "&chdate= " + chdate + " 
    &chamount= " + chamount + "", "_blank", 
    "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,top=10,left=10", "true");
          };
</script>
```